# ctrl+super+d doesn't toggle minimize/maximize all windows but only minimize all

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.2 32 bit platform, it's a fresh installation. I noticed that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it only minimize all windows but when I press them again windows remain hidden. I activated `hide/show` icon from `system settings` on Unity launcher, it runs well, I want to programatically manipulate it by means of `xdotool key super+d` but it only minimize all windows. Is it by design or something wrong with my system?